# Aggregated Content in iReport

Tags: export, jasper-reports, aggregate, ireport, subreport

Is is possible to aggregate content in iReport? What i mean is to do what "group by" does in sql?

Example:
name    brands  sales
joe     philips 120
bart    phlips  240
bart    sony    320
andy    nad     100

I use JRBeanCollectionDataSource to display detailed intel, but in summary band i have an aggregate subreport. Can i use only ireport features and the same DataSource to do it?
Another question is, why subreport appear in only in my xhtml page and when i export it to pdf, it doesn'? I can't export subreports. The place where it should be is blank.

Answer (score 1):

> Is is possible to aggregate content in iReport? What i mean is to do
>   what "group by" does in sql?

Yes, iReport has Grouping mechanism. You can create group (or several groups) for this purpose and use Group bands after that. You can find sample in iReport folder (%IREPORT_HOME%\ireport\samples\Groups).

> Can i use only ireport features and the same DataSource to do it?

I think, yes.

> Another question is, why subreport appear in only in my xhtml page and when i export it to pdf, it doesn'?

This is another case. There are no any reasons for this behavior if your template is well-formed. I think this is a problem of your implementation. You can check subreport sample in iReport folder (%IREPORT_HOME%\ireport\samples\Subreports).